# Eclipse plugin management in IBM RAD

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-rad, eclipse-marketplace

I installed RAD 7.5 and found out that IBM is not as good as I thought of it.
RAD thing has it's own  "install manager" which doesn't seem to resolve any dependencies.
Does anyone know how to enable standart eclipse's software installer and/or Eclipse Marketplace?

Comment: I checked eclipse 3.4 and figured out that was misled by installer's looks. ChrisGerken was right, it was native installer. I haven't found acceptable solution. But that's another question's topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to enable "classic install" in the preferences and then use the traditional installer to bring in 3rd party features.  Even so, you'll still need to use IBM's installation manager to apply fixes, upgrades and new components from IBM/Rational.

Comment: Well, if you know exactly how to do it,  describe please.

Comment: Sorry, from your wording I thought you were more familiar with Eclipse.  For RSA 7.5, go to the preferences page and expand General --> Capabilities.  In the list of capabilities, look for "Classic Update" and enable it by clicking on the checkbox.  Click on OK to close the preferences dialog.  From then on, you can go to Help --> Software Updates to install from traditional update sites.  You just add the site to the list by clicking "Add Site..." and then "Install..." once you've chosen the features you want.

Comment: First: i'm familliar with eclipse quite well, but not with RAD. In this particular matter they are different. Second: you wrote how to turn on "IBM's classic installer", which was in RAD 7.0 and then was replaced by new one in 7.5. I thought i've clearly specified that i'm intrested in native Eclipse's install manager and Marketplace.

Answer (score 11):

This is how you add Marketplace client plugin to RAD 7.x/8.x:

1. Help / Install New Software
2. Point to Eclipse Helios Site
   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios in "Available Software Sites"
3. Select the correct release (for RAD 8.0 is Helios)
4. Type "Marketplace" in filter text control
5. Check "General Purpose Tools / Marketplace Client"
6. After install restart RAD

You now should see Eclipse Marketplace in Help menu.

Hint: this is the same procedure as in Eclipse Classic.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I don't work with RAD anymore, so I can't check your answer. Maybe someone else will find your answer useful. Best regards!

Comment: @AleksandrKravets I work with RAD, and have been searching everywhere for a solution. I can confirm that this works 100%, and is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For RAD,Version 9.0.0:

Try to install using the

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Select "General Purpose Tools / Marketplace Client"

Then  "Next - Finish"

Answer (score 0):

I use IBM's Rational Developer for Power Systems (which shares parentage with RAD, I think) and all the normal Eclipse plug-in & feature install options, as well as the Marketplace, are available.

You might have a corrupt install.

Might also be worth a call to IBM to see if they help identify why the options aren't available for you.

Comment: If you are talking about version 7.5, then could you share a screenshot of help menu? My install is not corrupt. It's just fact that RAD 7.5 is based on Eclipse 3.4 and most of plugins i need  require 3.6 or later.

Comment: Well that's your problem, then.  Move to RAD 8.

Comment: Well, since plug-in's are often tied very tightly to the version of Eclipse they are based on, I don't think you're going to be able to upgrade the Eclipse version from 3.4 to 3.6.

I just checked my RDP 7.5 help menu and it does have "Software Updates" on it ... launch that menu option and the 2nd tab, Available Software, on that software updates and add-ons dialog gives you the ability to install plug-in's.

If you need Eclipse 3.6 plug-in's, I concur with @chris-gerken, upgrade to RAD 8.0 (RDp 8.0 is also based on Eclipse 3.6).

Comment: FWIW: A screen shot of the RDp 7.5 help menu can be found here: http://urlq.us/5-, and the software update dialog can be found here: http://urlq.us/60

Comment: @ChrisGerken: you are not constructive. I use tools bought by company.  Are you suggesting me to waste my own money to buy RAD 8?