# TestNG will not install on Rad 8.5

Tags: eclipse, testng, ibm-rad, testng-eclipse

I am trying to install TestNG on Rad 8.5.  I go to `Help->Install new software` and then put `http://beust.com/eclipse/` in the `Work with:` window and click on `Add`.  I then put `TestNG` as the `Name:` in the `Add Repository` window which pops up.  When I click `OK` nothing is listed to install so I can't finish the installation.  `http://beust.com/eclipse/` is listed on the `Available Software Sites` page but TestNG is not an option when I look at `File->New`.  All of the help pages I can find deal with Eclipse and say this is how to do it.  Normally Eclipse instructions work with Rad but something isn't working this time.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I found a way to add `Eclipse Marketplace` to Rad at [Add Eclipse Marketplace to Rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145567/eclipse-plugin-management-in-ibm-rad) but when I tried to use it I got an error message saying `the following connectors are not available: TestNG for eclipse` so there must be something wrong with the site.  Is there a way to check?

Comment: hi @ponder275, what's the eclipse version of IBM RAD 8.5 ?

Comment: The Eclipse platform is Version: 3.6.3.r362_v20110302-9gF78GsCFrIGnIGHpoPftwjnBiA8C-TZRswZYu

Comment: let's try to see if it's network issue or not. could you confirm if you're behind the company firewall and the http proxy correctly configured in RAD? or you can download [this archive update site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60126762/testng_plugin_updatesite.zip), save to your local file system, install plugin via archive.

Comment: I am behind the company firewall.  My Network Connections Active Provider is Native.  Should I change it to manual?  I tried to go to the archive update site and my company firewall blocked it due to "
This Websense category is filtered: Personal Network Storage and Backup. "

Comment: OK, could you try  to run the following curl command: `curl -L -v http://beust.com/eclipse`,  and see if it works or not, or might the site is blocked by your company firewall. (Note, you might need to configure the http_proxy for curl,)